# How can I change HTML content on hover in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, mouseover, destructuring

Here is the header section of my website-to-be.

[image: Eds header section]

**Primary goal:**

To hover over an icon and change the **Logo** text in the top right to reflect the icon which is being hovered over. For example, hovering over the second icon **</>** will change '**edwin*d*harris**' to '**projects**'. The default needs to be 'edwindharris'.

**Secondary goal:**

For the transition between the changing headings to be a quick (.2s ish) fade.

Here is the incomplete code I have so far, which I would greatly appreciate help in completing:

```
const HeaderDesktop = () => {

    const homeHeading = {
        default:'edwin' + '<em>d</em>' + 'harris',
        home: 'home',
        projects: 'projects',
        design: 'design',
        about: 'about'
    }

    const Logo = () => {
        return (
            <LogoContainer>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: homeHeading.default}}/>
            </LogoContainer>
        );
    }

    return (
       <DesktopHeader>
            <Link to={'/'}><HomeSvg/></Link>
            <Link to={'/projects'}><ProjectsSvg/></Link>
            <Link to={'/design'}><DesignSvg/></Link>
            <Link to={'/about'}><AboutSvg/></Link>
            <Logo/>
       </DesktopHeader>
    );
}

export default HeaderDesktop;
```

I have removed attempts at implementing a fade / changing the text on hover so as to keep this post clear. Everything I have tried before posting has not been pretty!

*Note: **LogoContainer** & **DesktopHeader** and the **Svg**s are Styled Components.*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store heading value in a state and then update the heading with relevant value on onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave.

Example:

```
import {useState} from "react";

const HeaderDesktop = () => {
    
    const defaultHeading = 'edwin' + '<em>d</em>' + 'harris'
    const [heading, setHeading] = useState(defaultHeading)

    const Logo = ({heading}) => {
        return (
            <LogoContainer>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: heading}}/>
            </LogoContainer>
        );
    }

    const setDefaultPageHeading = () => setHeading(defaultHeading)

    return (
        <DesktopHeader>
            <Link to={'/'}><HomeSvg/></Link>
            <Link to={'/projects'}>
                <span
                    onMouseEnter={()=> setHeading('projects')}
                    onMouseLeave={setDefaultPageHeading}
                >
                    <ProjectsSvg/>
                </span>
            </Link>
            <Link to={'/design'}>
                <span
                    onMouseEnter={()=> setHeading('design')}
                    onMouseLeave={setDefaultPageHeading}
                >
                    <DesignSvg/>
                </span>
            </Link>
            <Link to={'/about'}>
                <span
                    onMouseEnter={()=> setHeading('about')}
                    onMouseLeave={setDefaultPageHeading}
                >
                   <AboutSvg/>
                </span>
            </Link>
            <Logo heading={heading}/>
        </DesktopHeader>
    );
}

export default HeaderDesktop;
```

Comment: Thank you, Umar. I think I follow, but I am not sure how to implement that to work with each icon targeting the same text element. Any chance you could drop an example in? It's probably super obvious, but I am fairly new to React.

Comment: Hi @edwindharris, I have updated the answer panel with an example code. can you please try that !!!

Comment: You have smashed my primary objective out of the park! Thank you very much, Umar! Awesome!

Comment: Aah, that's great @edwindharris, glad to be of help. Cheers :) !!!